# Does a method get instantiated together with an object?

Tags: java, oop, object, memory-management

Let's say I got the following class:

```
public class Human(){

    String eyeColor;

    public Human(String faceDescription){
           this.eyecolor = determineEyeColor(faceDescription);
    }

    private String determineEyeColor(String faceDescription){
          String eyeColor;
          <algorithm that extracts the actual eye color substring">
          return eyeColor;
    }
}
```

And in my main method I got a call like:

```
String faceDescription = "<String where a face gets described in detail>";
Human human = new Human(faceDescription);
```

If I now form a List of let's say 10 000 Human() objects. Does the determineEyeColor() method (since its INSIDE the Human class) get instanciated 10 000 times too, and therefore is a big memory sink? Is there a **substantial difference** in terms of ressources if I program it this way:

```
public class Human(){

   String eyeColor;

   public Human(String eyeColor){
          this.eyecolor = eyeColor;
   }
}
```

Put the determineEyeColor() method **outside ** of the Human class
and make the call in my main method this way:

```
String faceDescription = "<String where a face gets described in detail>";
Human human = new Human(determineEyeColor(faceDescription));
```

The method gets called on every instanciation too.
The codeblock of determineEyeColor() itself is written also only 1 time in my overall code.

The only difference is that the **algorithm itself** doesn't get instanciated inside every object right? I basically don't have 10 000 x determineEyeColor() in every Human() instance.

The downside of this is that I can't just reuse this class instantly on other programs since I also need to make changes to the instantiating class ( adding the determineEyeColor() to the instantiating class).

Is this even true? Does the method get instantiated in every Human() instance or does Java recognize this and share the method over all objects, only using different fields mapped to the respective instance of Human().

Comment: The code belongs to the class, and is not duplicated in each Human instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Object-oriented programming, an instance of a class only holds the data. Methods belong to the class and are the code is shared across all objects.

The purpose of the data (properties of the object) is to determine how the methods behave. Thus, depending on the data each method will behave differently, but the method code does not change for each object.

When you instantiate 10 000 objects of the class `Human` you are creating 10 000 containers for the data, tied to the implementation of the `Human` class. This means that you can execute the methods of the `Human` class on each set of data. A call to a method of an object might produce a different outcome despite executing the same code block.

Comment: So the code of `determineEyeColor()` is shared among all 10 000 objects and not instantiated uniquely in every of the 10 000 objects. It is placed in memory basicly 1x and shared whereas the properties of the object naturally are present 10 000x in the memory since they have specific values.Conclusion: Wether the method is outside of  `Human()` class or inside will in fact make no difference in terms of performance or memory occupied.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of doing this.
It is true, that if you instantiate, and maintain in scope, a Human object for each input, then lot's of human objects will exist, but if in your processing structure, the Human object falls out of scope, then Garbage Collection will eventually tidy up for you.

There is a whole separate debate around whether you should have fields in your input, rather than just a string, but that's another issue.

Comment: My question is basicly will an object `List<Human> listOfHumans`  be different ( smaller in terms of ressource needs ) with those 2 ways of implementing ? One version with the determineEyeColor() method in every of the elements inside the list and the other with externally calling the method and just passing the determined eyecolor String to the object ! Not sure why it was downvoted too... maybe the question is too simple or something. Well thanks for your answere :)

Comment: Do you mean that the garbage collector will also clean up the method after i have called it in the constructor, and therefore ther eisnt much difference in a final `List<Human> listOfHumans` ?